# Handling DB errors in MVVM SL4

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

Quick example: An error occurred when attempting to save a record to a db. Or perhaps a timeout occurred on a job.

In MVVM, that's going to occur in my Model or DB Access layer. What's the method for handling that error (elegantly)?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda of a big question.

Also it is very dependent on your user requirements.

For example:

Do you need just to show the user that something went wrong?

Simply put a property with a message, and a property to indicate a faulted state and have your View change itself accordingly.

Do you need to limit access until you can fix something?

Your VM can easily disable commands until you have re-initiated your connection or some other measure.

Perhaps if you have a scenario in mind, I can be more specific :)

HTH

Ariel

Comment: I guess the question was more geared around - are there any definitive resources out there that define any sort of pattern or end-to-end process? My client has an existing error handling class for their .NET apps, including error logging & whatnot, and we'd like to recreate it using the MVVM pattern & its best practices.